# Reactjs material ui textfield number max and min

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers, material-ui, textfield

[image: Registrazione schermo 2020-11-20 alle 17 21 03]

I have an input field which should only take values between min and max.

I did as shown below, but entering the number manually as seen in the image bypasses the control.

How can I do?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5509t?file=/demo.js)

```
<TextField
          id="outlined-number"
          label="Number max number 10"
          type="number"
          InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: "0", max: "10", step: "1" } }}
          variant="outlined"
          handleChange('number')
        />
```

My handleChange:

```
const handleChange = field => ({ target: { value } }) => {
        setState(prev => {
            const _item = prev.item;
            _item[field] = value;
            return { ...prev, item: _item };
        });
    };

handleChange('nameAttr')
```

Comment: yup thats how its work, try to change the value onBlur

Comment: In what sense, could you give an example?

Comment: I added a answer, hope it will helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TextField as a controlled component to prevent the input to be more than 10. You should also use an additional state variable for that.

The code is as follows (Replace the component with the component given below and import useEffect additionally)

```
export default function FormPropsTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  function handler(e) {
    if (Number(e.target.value) > 10) {
      setValue(10);
    }else{
      setValue(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-number"
          label="Number max number 10"
          type="number"
          InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: "0", max: "10", step: "1" } }}
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={handler}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

So if the input value is more than 10, it prevents updating the state variable `value` thanks to our logic in the `handler` function. This is not the best solution and you may want to build upon you logic based on this example.

Comment: I have to keep my generic handleChange (see above), I can't create a custom one.

Comment: As another user pointed out, onBlur seems to be your best bet.

Comment: Another solution I think I have found would be to use useEffect on the variable that should change state and check them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late but it worked for me

```
const minValue = 0  //Or whichever number you want
const maxValue = 10
const [value, setValue] = useState(minValue)

//Executes when the value changes
const handle = (e) => {
    const newValue = Math.min(Math.max(e.target.value, minValue), maxValue)
    setValue(previousValue => newValue)
}
```

Then in yout TextField you do...

```
    <TextField
      id="outlined-number"
      label="Number max number 10"
      type="number"
      variant="outlined"
      handleChange(e => handle(e))
      value={value}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

set a function to `onChange` of the text input

set a state of the number

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
```

set the value of the text input to the `number` and then add the `onChange` event

```
<TextField
    ....
    onChange={validateNumber}
    value={number}
/>

const validateNumber = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  const setValue = value <= 10 ? value : number; //if the input value is greater than 10, then don't change the input value
  setNumber(setValue);
};
```

[Updated Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-trk6u?file=/demo.js:425-591)

Comment: I have to keep my generic handleChange (see above), I can't create a custom one.

Comment: @Paul pls update your your code-sandbox demo, it doesn't have `handleChange`

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-hxflw?file=/demo.js

Use onBlur or onChange to adjust your value to your max.

Using your onChange:

```
const handleChange = field => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setState(prev => {
        const _item = prev.item;
        _item[field] = parseInt(value) > 10 ? "10" : value;
        return { ...prev, item: _item };
    });
};
```

Comment: Maybe at the moment it is the best solution I'm thinking about it, I have an idea, but I don't know which of the two is the best solution to use.

Comment: @Paul added example for your onChange

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late late on this one. But this worked for me, using outlinedInput

```js
import { OutlinedInput } from '@mui/material'

<OutlinedInput
  type="number"
  value={someVariable}
  onChange={(e) => setSomeVariable(e.target.value >= 0 ? parseInt(e.target.value) : 0)}

/>
```